# Getting the type for an key to define function argument

Tags: typescript, function

I have an type like the follow example

```
export type Signals = {
    activity: boolean;
    quest: string;
    creator: number;
}
```

With this type i would get an function that has followed properties

```
export function initStation<T>(){
    return {
        signal: (id: keyof T, value: T[keyof T]){
            // code
        }
    }
}
```

But when i use this implemetation i have all the time an union type vor the value argument. Even when the id argument is setted as activity, quest or creator.

I try to get a better support, when the id is for example equal activity then the possible type is just a boolean, cause in my type above is activity defined as boolean.

I expected to call my function like

```
const station = initStation<Signals>()

station.signal('activity', true); // fine
station.signal('quest', 'any quest'); // fine
station.signal('creator', 1234); // fine
```

and getting error when i try to use the function like below

```
station.signal('activity', 'abc'); // error
station.signal('quest', 123); // error
station.signal('creator', true); // error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id` is of type `keyof T` and `value` is of type `T[keyof T]`, then they will both be uncorrelated [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) and nothing will stop someone from passing in an `id` and a `value` corresponding to different properties from `T`.  One way to fix this is to make your method [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of `id`, `K extends keyof T`, and then have `value` represented in terms of that:

```
export function initStation<T>() {
  return {
    signal: <K extends keyof T>(id: K, value: T[K]){
      // code
    }
  }
}
```

This gives you the behavior you desire:

```
const station = initStation<Signals>();

station.signal('activity', true); // fine
station.signal('quest', 'any quest'); // fine
station.signal('creator', 1234); // fine
station.signal('activity', 'abc'); // error
station.signal('quest', 123); // error
station.signal('creator', true); // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKBLA5gOwIYA2AznALxwDeAUHHHgMYwYBuGSAXHAEYQQHB4cAbhpwAjgFdgRGJxlQMOLCNr0oAmNE44JAWy7AoIgL5UzoSLDgAzCTkYYIOOIrZoYeJk4A8AFQB8ABQAlJSi6jASUM7UtLRE2PgEnN4A0nCgMMA4ACYkANbAiBDWcAGBGDmcqQA0cMyEUpy+ANqpALrBsXG0APS9cPQQOcCitKbjVKZUQzgycDKejs7krjDuSz6YuIREQcEiVIteOAB0CTsEgQDkDEysSNd1MFBSB3D9Noqjx8vniYQbpJpDAnnBbjhEOIpDJru9PtZvkcPCd-pcbmoNNAwQBGABMAGYACzwgaInA-FF-C5JG53FhsRBg25cehwoQfAaGKDQZGbM40wHXYGwur4gmkjJQHlQPmowVXa6YzzY56vYCS7m8oA)