# Create function signture by type

Tags: typescript, interface

How is it possible to create function signature by type?
I can create function signature like this.

```
type Data = {
    update: boolean
};

type Distribution<T> = {
    on: <K extends keyof T>(key: K, listener: (value: T[K]) => void) => void;
    set: <K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]) => void;
};

const dataDistribution: Distrobution<Data> ...;

dataDistribution.set('update', true) // function signature has the key update and boolean as value
```

What is well described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74880637/8540217

But how can i reduce the second argument when the type is like

```
type Data = {
    update: void
};
```

or

```
type Data = {
    update: never
};
```

to get the function signature without error?

```
dataDistribution.set('update') // Expected 2 arguments, but got 1
```

Is this basicly possible, without defining second argument as optional?
For reasons beyond my control I cannot accept any solution that uses `undefined`.

Comment: I think you want `undefined` there and not `never` or `void`.

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6xZRm) what you're looking for? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thanks man, changed typo :) undefined is not possible. it is not allowed by .eslintrc rules

Comment: ? I don't understand why you'd allow a property of type `void` but not `undefined`. [The `void` type](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#void) is weird and best avoided.  `never` is also bizarre because a value with a `never`-valued property cannot exist.  I don't see this question depending on eslint anyway.  If the question prohibits use of `undefined` then please [edit] to make that clear and I can either run away screaming or do [this](//tsplay.dev/w847pw) to bring it back (since optional properties will automatically allow `undefined`). How do you want to proceed?

Comment: It is a project and the eslint is already adjusted. i can't change the elsint.
thats the reason why i ask here. maybe someone knows a better solution. otherwise i will run away and scream as well. :)

Comment: So please [edit] the question and say something like "for reasons beyond my control I cannot accept any solution that uses `undefined`".  And then if someone feels like answering a question with such a... uh, *unique* constraint, they can do so.  I mean, I could write [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlDO5N), but I wouldn't want to write an answer saying that.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding on discussion in the comments, still exists now a better solution for this issue.
For this has helped the understanding of [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlDO5N) from [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz).

The starting point is:

- `undefined` is not allowed
- function signature depence on the generic type

**First step**

Cloned the [Option](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) implementation from [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/).

This would help to prevent undefined for optional types.

```
export type Option<T> = {
    isNone(): boolean;
    isSome(): boolean;
    unwrap(): T;
    unwrapOr(alternativeOpt: T): T;
    expect(msg: string): T;
};

export const option = <T>(opt?: T): Option<T> => {
    const isNone = () => opt === undefined || opt === null;
    const isSome = () => !isNone();
    const unwrap = () => {
        if (isNone()) throw new Error('option is none');

        return opt as T;
    };
    const unwrapOr = (alternativeOpt: T) => {
        if (isSome()) return unwrap();

        return alternativeOpt as T;
    };
    const expect = (msg: string) => {
        if (isSome()) return unwrap();
        throw new Error(msg);
    };

    return { isNone, isSome, unwrap, unwrapOr, expect };
};
```

**Second step**

Changed type for the distribution implemenation to get the function signature regarding on the generic type and switch optionls into the `Option<T>` implementation.

*This solution was possible with the understanding from [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlDO5N)*

*Thanks to [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz)*

```
export type DistributorOn<T> = <K extends keyof T>(
    key: K extends string ? K : never,
    listener: T[K] extends (...args: never[]) => void
        ? T[K]
        : (value: T[K] extends NonNullable<T[K]> ? T[K] : Option<Exclude<T[K], null | undefined>>) => void,
) => DistributorListener;

export type DistributorSend<T> = <K extends keyof T>(
    key: K extends string ? K : never,
    ...rest: T[K] extends () => void
        ? [value?: never]
        : T[K] extends (...args: never[]) => void
        ? Parameters<T[K]>
        : T[K] extends NonNullable<T[K]>
        ? [value: T[K]]
        : [value: Option<Exclude<T[K], null | undefined>>]
) => void;

export type Distributor<T> = {
    on: DistributorOn<T>;
    send: DistributorSend<T>;
};
```

**Last stepe**
Try it

```
type MyDistrobution = {
    name: string;
    age?: number;
    hook: () => void;
    msg: (subject: string, msg: string) => void;
};

const myDistro = distributor<MyDistrobution>();

// for MyDistrobution.name
myDistro.on('name', (name) => consoe.log(name); // <-- will be Marie Juana
myDistro.send('name', 'Marie Juana');

// for MyDistrobution.age
myDistro.on('age', (age) => console.log(age.isNone()); // <-- will be true
myDistro.send('age', option());

myDistro.on('age', (age) => consolelog(age.isSome())); // <-- will be false
myDistro.send('age', option(123));

// for MyDistrobution.hook
myDistro.on('hook', () => console.log('called'));
myDistro.send('hook');

// for MyDistrobution.msg
myDistro.on('msg', console.log); // <-- will be foobar, hello world
myDistro.send('msg', 'foobar', 'hello world');
```